# Regex: strip text within string

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have text like

```
5 Cm Per Second - Makoto Shinkai Collection (2007) 3xDVD5 Copia 11 ITA JAP FRA MultiSub
Ai City - La Notte Dei Cloni (1986) DVD9 ITA JAP Sub ITA
Akira - The Ultimate Edition 3xDVD9_5 MULTI
AIKA (1997) (2xDVD5) MHost Ita Serie Completa
```

I want to obtain 3 different solutions
**1.** *name + (year)*

```
5 Cm Per Second - Makoto Shinkai Collection (2007)
Abenobashi (2002)
Ai City - La Notte Dei Cloni
Akira - The Ultimate Edition (2005)
```

**2.** *only year*

```
2007
1986
<empty row> => I need to mantain like empty row
1997
```

**3.**  *description*

```
3xDVD5 Copia 11 ITA JAP FRA MultiSub
(4xDVD9) MHost Ita Serie Completa
The Ultimate Edition 3xDVD9_5 MULTI
(2xDVD5) MHost Ita Serie Completa
```

##

I try these regex on Notepad++ (replace is empty)

1. `^.*(?=\))`
2. `\((.*?)\]`
3. `I don't know`

but don't work well, can't strip text within entire string

**@zzxyz**

I try your regex but don't works if I have

```
Hayao Miyazaki Collection (1979 - 2009) FullHD 1080p
Milo su Marte (2010) BluRay Rip 1080p x264 MKV ITA ENG - NST
Tokyo Ghoul (2014) BDRip 1080p DTS-HD MA 5.1+AC3 5.1 ITA AC3 2.0 JAP Sub ITA MKV-FBT
```

Comment: Do you mean you want to match and replace - name + year, only year and description - by something else?

Comment: Or you want to match the opposite, and replace it with empty, to keep name + year, only year and description visible?

Comment: I want 3 different regex for each 1,2,3 examples. If I have _Ai City - La Notte Dei Cloni (1986) DVD9 ITA JAP Sub ITA_ 1st solution should be `Abenobashi (2002)`, 2nd solution regex should be `1986`, 3rd regex should be return `(4xDVD9) MHost Ita Serie Completa`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your problem(s) it's better to capture the text you DO want and replace the whole line with that.  This captures the data you are interested in and allows you to rebuild it however you'd like (in the replace line):

```
^(.*?) \s? (\(\d{4}\))? \s? (\(?\d*?x?DVD.*?)$
```

`$1` is the name, `$2` is the date (optional), `$3` is the description

https://regex101.com/r/Y8MbHO/2

Oh, and sorry.  **You need to remove the spaces in the regex.**  I put those in for clarity.

So your replace string for #1 is `$1 $2`, for #2 is `$2`, and for #3 is `$3`.

And I should note a `\(\)` is a literal paren whereas `()` is a capture group.  So the date part: `(\(\d{4}\))?` would look like `\(?(\d{4})?\)?` if you didn't want to capture `(1986)` but wanted to capture `1986`

EDIT:
If the date is always there, you would use:

```
^(.*?) \s? (\(\d{4}-?\d*?\)) \s? (.*?)$
```

Comment: Good way but.. Is possible to generalize values for this regex ? Because I can have not only _DVD_ but also _BDRip 1080p, BluRay Rip, FullHD 1080p.._ and between brackets I can have something like (1979 - 2009)

Comment: To a point.  But if the date is optional, you need to have SOME way of telling the regex where the description begins (or the name ends).  If that can look like anything....That's not parsable.

Comment: I update question, I try used `^(.*?) \s? (\(\d{4}\))? \s? (\(?\d.*?)$`, it works for $3, but no for $2, and for $1 it remove year (I have for example  _Milo su Marte (2010)_ but regex remove year _Milo su Marte_, where I wrong ?

Comment: I'm not sure how it could work for #3 since you're requiring the description to start with a digit or a paren and a digit.   (`\d`)

Comment: yes, I see now, it doesn't work because begin from year, you are right, but how should I change your 3d capture group `(\(?\d*?x?DVD.*?)$` to generalize ? because your regex filter only if present DVD text but I need any string after year/date

Comment: So as it stands with the edit, I don't think your question is answerable.  You need a definitive list of all the ways the description can start, OR you need to consider the date non-optional and not process lines that don't contain a date.

Comment: no, zzxyz, I need to capture 3rd group better and any 3rd group is _always_ after *(year)*, so your regex is good and correct but is limited to DVD text within, I wish to remove that limit but I don't understand how edit your 3rd group correctly

Comment: @JackyNed - So the year will ALWAYS be there?

Comment: yes, is always _between_ text strings = between $1-$3 and year/date is always inside brackets

Comment: Okay, your question has an example where it isn't there.  But I've updated my answer.